# Add the section number to a list of tables in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, context

I have some tables inside `\startsection`..`\stopsection` environments and I want them to be listed below the general TOC.

So I have the following in the first part of my project structure:

```
\startsubject[title={Contenido}]
\placecontent
\stopsubject
\startsubject[title={Lista de tablas}]
\placelistoftables
\stopsubject
```

And I have this setup for that list:

```
\setuplist[table][alternative=c]
```

But [reading the wiki on `\setuplist`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuplist) and played with all those *pageprefix** arguments I can't figure how to include the section number as a prefix for the table number, so it would show up sort of like

1.1  A table here . . . . . . . . . . . . 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust the counter to number by section and display it as part of the prefix.

```
\setupcaption
  [table]
  [way=bysection,
   prefixsegments=section]

\starttext

\startsubject[title={Contenido}]
  \placecontent
\stopsubject

\startsubject[title={Lista de tablas}]
  \placelistoftables
\stopsubject

\startsection[title={A section here}]

\startplacetable
  [title={A table here}]
  \startTABLE
    \NC foo \NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopplacetable

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]